# End of the human race

Tags: story-identification

An egotistical rich man decides he wants to start the human race over with he and his wife as the new Adam and Eve.  He laces dollar bills with an infertility drug and flies around the world dropping the bills out of planes.  He thinks his wife is protected from touching them, but she ends up touching one. Does anyone recognize this story?

Comment: Welcome to SFF! Was this a novel or a short story? When did you read it, and how old was the story? Was it written in English or another language? Where in the world was it (mostly) set? Any details you can remember might help someone to identify it. See also [our](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/31394) [guidance](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9336/31394) on asking good story-ID questions.

Comment: Sounds like Inuits and other first peoples that (still) don't touch the money might be the new Adam and Eve. Also, sources of infertility are diagnosable.  Once folks found out, the newborns and kids who hadn't touched the poison would still be around.  This means that while there would be a population implosion, the effect would be imperfect anywhere that the birth rate was nonzero.

Comment: Money as a vector for attacking women is the start of the plot of Herbert's [*The White Plague*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_White_Plague).